# Removing type checking by using Spring bean id's

Tags: java, spring

I've written a state machine for navigating an automated telephone system, where each state is represented by its own Java class file, for a total of 50+ classes. Rather than write the instantiation and factory code myself, I decided to use Spring for bean definition and dependency injection. This works fine, however I have lost compile-time type checking by moving from:

```
State next = getState(Instructions.class);
```

to

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ...
State next = ctx.getBean("instructions", State.class);
```

Instead of having compiler checks that I've specified a real, existing state, I now have to rely on the id being spelled properly in both my source code and the bean xml.

Is there a better way to do this? I haven't worked extensively with Spring since early 2.0 days, so I don't have much real world experience to draw on. What are the drawbacks and advantages of this approach? Is there is something extra I could to to verify proper id strings are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off lazy initialization of Spring, and you'll at least cure the type safety department. You could also consider a 'grand central station' bean into which *all* of the states are inserted by name, this resulting in a yell if any go missing. You can still mispell in your Java code.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm not mistaken, eager initialization is default in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Spring autowiring and in your class have:

```
class StateMachine
{
    @Autowired
    State next;
}
```

You can also use qualifiers to select amongst the different implementation you may have of State.

Comment: I would recommend JSR 330's @Inject though, as it does not tie you to Spring (javax.inject.Inject vs. org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go about it one of two ways:

1) If only a few states needed access to a few other states, I would inject those directly (like Steve said in his answer):

```
@Inject
public setInstructions(Instructions instructions) { ... }
```

2) On the other hand, if any state needs access to any other one, no one wants to inject the other 49 states into each of the 50 classes, so I would have one central class that had all 50 injected and basically build my state machine in that class.

Spring really is a factory when it comes down to it, but tying yourself to the Spring API kind of goes against their philosophy, and as you mentioned, you lose type safety.